# null values for instead of date causes the browser to crash while using chart js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

[image: This is screeenshot of the error that i am getting]I am using the chart.js library to show the time on X-axis and corresponding Y-axis value. when I pass some value for x as null then it crashes the browser. If I pass all x values as null then it works fine (doesn't crashes the browser). It is failing in the `moment.js` with

I gone through this thread and upgraded my `chart.js` version to `2.7.2`. But still facing the same issue.

Here's the sample data that I am using:

```
        { x: "2019-04-05 16:06:48", y: 89 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 16:03:47", y: 52 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 16:00:48", y: 31 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 15:57:49", y: 76 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 15:54:49", y: 4 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 15:51:49", y: 39 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 15:48:49", y: 11 }
```

this  works fine as there is no null for any x-value, but if I replace some x value as follows then it fails:

```
        { x: "2019-04-05 16:06:48", y: 89 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 16:03:47", y: 52 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 16:00:48", y: 31 },
        { x: null, y: 76 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 15:54:49", y: 4 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 15:51:49", y: 39 },
        { x: "2019-04-05 15:48:49", y: 11 }
```

I expect it should render graph even with null values for `x` same as if I replace the `x` values with `null` in this given example: 
https://embed.plnkr.co/JOI1fpgWIS0lvTeLUxUp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded `chart.js` version from `2.8.0` to `2.6.0` and this worked for me. I think there is any bug in the latest (2.8.0) version of the `chart.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess momentjs doesn't like trying to convert null to a date. So I would recommend checking for null before you provide it to momentjs or think about some default value - which is a date, but don't use null.

If you don't care, you can put

```
moment().format() // instead of null
```

Comment: it is handled by `chart.js`  which is calling `moment.js` functions. `chart.js` supports `null` values in the data.

Comment: moment(null).format() --> "Invalid date", how is chart.js supposed to show it?

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/JOI1fpgWIS0lvTeLUxUp/  this is a link to example if you pass replace any date with `null` it creates a break in the graph and doesn't throw any error in the library on which `chart.js` is dependent in this case `moment.js`

Comment: Did you try using same versions, which are in the demo for momentjs and Chart.js

Comment: Yes, I did but no result